# How is this possible to call OneToOneField values in admin using list_display=[]

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin, django-admin-filters

my model

```
    class user_profile(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    age = models.IntegerField()

    profile_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
```

> **admin.py**

```
class UserProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
list_display = ['user','user.username','profile_created', 'timestamp']
admin.site.register(user_profile, UserProfileAdmin)
```

It show the following error(s):

`ERRORS:
<class 'testapp.admin.UserProfileAdmin'>: (admin.E108) The value of 'list_display[1]' refers to 'user.username', which is not a call
able, an attribute of 'UserProfileAdmin', or an attribute or method on 'testapp.user_profile'.`

How can I fetch another table values in `admin.py`?

Comment: It should be **`'user__username'`** instead of `'user.username'`

Comment: Not working same error. ERRORS:
<class 'testapp.admin.UserProfileAdmin'>: (admin.E108) The value of 'list_display[0]' refers to 'user__username', which is not a cal
lable, an attribute of 'UserProfileAdmin', or an attribute or method on 'testapp.user_profile'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the [**PEP8**](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names), class names should normally use the *CapWords* convention.

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    # your code
```

also, to show the *username* in DjangoAdmin, you should define a method as,

```
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist


class UserProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['user', 'username', 'profile_created', 'timestamp']

    def username(self, instance): # name of the method should be same as the field given in `list_display`
        try:
            return instance.user.username
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            return 'ERROR!!'

admin.site.register(UserProfile, UserProfileAdmin)
```

Comment: Brilliant, it's working thank you bro. thank you soooo much... bro. It similarly working for ManyToMany or ManyToOne relations also?